# like and unlike with javascript and Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to implement a functionality where user can like and unlike product using javascript I followed this [Laravel - Favourite / Un-Favourite button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438613/laravel-favourite-un-favourite-button?rq=1) but it doesn't work for me, the button can't be clicked, any idea on how I can fix this?

Routes

```
Route::get('product/like/{id}', ['as' => 'product.like', 'uses' =>   'LikeController@likeProduct']);
Route::get('product/{product}/unlike','LikeController@destroy')->name('product.unlike');
```

Javascript

```
 <script>

function addToFavourites(productid, userid) {
var user_id = userid;
var product_id = productid;

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'product/like/{id}',
    data: {
        'user_id': user_id,
        'product_id': product_id,
    },
    success: function () {
        // hide add button
        $('#addfavourites' + product_id).hide();
        // show delete button
        $('#deletefavourite' + product_id).show();
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        // handle error
    }
});
}
```

Blade file

```
   @if($product->isLiked)
      <div id="addfavourites{{$product->id}}" onClick="addToFavourites({{$product->id}}, {{ Auth::user()->id }})"> unlike </div>
       @else
       <div id="deletefavourite{{$product->id}}" onClick="deleteFromFavourites({{$product->id}}, {{ Auth::user()->id }})" > like </div>
    @endif
```

Comment: check your blade file. this is wrong `onClick="addToFavourites({{$product->id}}"`

Comment: I checked it and adding the missing code but still is not working @AndriyLozynskiy

Comment: check the ajax url `url: 'product/like/{id}',`. What is `{id}`?

Comment: `{id}` is the product->id @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Looks like it's harcoded to `'product/like/{id}',`. I think it should be `url: 'product/like/'+product_id,`

Comment: The button can't even be clicked after changing url to `product/like/'+product_id,` @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: I mean the button is just like h1, so if you press nothing happens @porloscerrosΨ